# COM: How to marshal block of memory from c++ com client to c#

Tags: c#, c++, com

I've read in [Memory management in COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308862/memory-management-in-com) that com can marshal block of memory. But how I can marshal block of memory from c++ com client to an out-of-process server written in c#?

I have following interface & implementation written in C#:

```
[Guid(...), ComVisible(true)]
public interface ISomeInterface
{
  void DoSomething(IntPtr memoryBlockPtr);
}  

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] 
[Guid(...), ComVisible(true)]
public class SomeObject : ISomeInterface
{
   public void DoSomething(IntPtr memoryBlockPtr) { 
      byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(memoryBlockPtr);
      ...
   } 
}
```

In tlb this interface becomes:

```
interface ISomeInterface : IDispatch {
  HRESULT DoSomething([in] long memoryBlockPtr);
};
```

In c++ com client I want to pass memory allocated by CoTaskMemAlloc to server

```
char * memoryBlockPtr = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
// write to memoryBlockPtr variable length structure 
// which could have char* fields that point to another memory block 
// allocated by CoTaskMemAlloc
HRESULT hr = ISomeInterface->DoSomething((long)memoryBlockPtr);
```

But this call fails because of com marshals long instead of memory block pointer and com server gets IntPtr that points to wrong memory block.